# How to change the bootstrap media queries conditions?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

We have bootstrap settings for large screen as:-

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}
```

I want to override to max-width : 1920px. How can I do this without hacking the core?

**Note:** I am maintaining my front end dependencies via bower, so I want the changes to be maintained on the custom CSS files. Is there any way to "override" those configurations?

Answer (score 3):

Use the customize page on the documentation to create a custom version.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

Answer (score 2):

You just need to update Bootstrap's `_variables.scss` file. These are all the variables available to you for changing the breakpoints:

```
$screen-xs:                  480px !default;
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
$screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;

$screen-sm:                  768px !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
$screen-tablet:              $screen-sm-min !default;

$screen-md:                  992px !default;
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;
$screen-desktop:             $screen-md-min !default;

$screen-lg:                  1200px !default;
$screen-lg-min:              $screen-lg !default;
$screen-lg-desktop:          $screen-lg-min !default;

$screen-xs-max:              ($screen-sm-min - 1) !default;
$screen-sm-max:              ($screen-md-min - 1) !default;
$screen-md-max:              ($screen-lg-min - 1) !default;
```

I'm not sure if this is what you meant by "hacking the core", but I assure you it's not that. These values are *meant* to be changed, as can be seen by their own comments in the file:

```
## Define the breakpoints at which your layout will change, adapting to different screen sizes.
```